# Gradle create a empty folder `build/kotlin/sessions`, why? When i delete it comes back, how to fix it?

Tags: gradle, kotlin, intellij-idea

I have a multi module project in Kotlin/Springboot with Gradle build.
I have a folder `build/kotlin/sessions` that always appear even if i delete it.

What is the folder and why is it there? Can i remove it completely so it does not come back?

[image]

My root `settings.gradle.kts`:

```
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        maven(url = "https://repo.spring.io/snapshot")

        maven(url = "https://repo.spring.io/milestone")

        gradlePluginPortal()
    }
    resolutionStrategy {
        eachPlugin {
            if (requested.id.id == "org.springframework.boot") {
                useModule("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${requested.version}")
            }
        }
    }
}

rootProject.name = "ris_2.0_backend"
include("workflow")
include("messaging")
include("project")
include("restapi")
```

My root `build.gradle.kts`:

```
plugins {
    id("io.spring.dependency-management") version "1.0.8.RELEASE"
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.3.61" apply false
    kotlin("plugin.spring") version "1.3.61"
    kotlin("plugin.jpa") version "1.3.61"
}

subprojects {

    apply(plugin = "io.spring.dependency-management")

    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencyManagement {
        imports {
            mavenBom("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:2.1.8.RELEASE") {
                bomProperty("kotlin.version", "1.3.61")
            }
        }
    }



}
```

And all `build.gradle.kts` in each module:

```
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile

plugins {
    id("com.adarshr.test-logger").version("1.7.0") // pretty log printing
    kotlin("jvm")
    kotlin("plugin.spring")
    jacoco
}

group = "no.inmeta.ris.workflow"
version = "0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"
val junit5Version = "5.5.1"

val developmentOnly = configurations.create("developmentOnly")

configurations.runtimeClasspath.get().extendsFrom(developmentOnly)

configurations {
    developmentOnly
    testCompile {
        exclude(group = "junit", module = "junit") // force junit5
        exclude(group = "mocito-core", module = "mockito-core")
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {

    // Spring
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa")


    // Swagger
    implementation("io.springfox:springfox-swagger2:2.9.2")

    // Testing
    implementation(enforcedPlatform("org.junit:junit-bom:$junit5Version"))
    testImplementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:2.1.9.RELEASE")
    testImplementation("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter")
    testRuntimeOnly("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine")
    testImplementation("org.assertj:assertj-core:3.11.1")

    // Kotlin testing library
    testImplementation("com.ninja-squad:springmockk:1.1.3")
    testImplementation("io.mockk:mockk:1.9.3")

    // Kotlin
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8")
    implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin:2.10.0")
}

configure<JacocoPluginExtension> {
    toolVersion = "0.8.4"
}

tasks.withType<JacocoReport> {
    reports {
        xml.isEnabled = true
        csv.isEnabled = false
        xml.destination = file("${buildDir}/jacoco/reports/test.xml")
        html.destination = file("${buildDir}/jacoco/reports/test.html")
    }
}

tasks.withType<Test> {
    useJUnitPlatform()
    testLogging {
        events("passed", "skipped", "failed")
    }
    finalizedBy("jacocoTestReport")
}

val compileKotlin: KotlinCompile by tasks
compileKotlin.kotlinOptions {
    jvmTarget = "1.8"
}
val compileTestKotlin: KotlinCompile by tasks
compileTestKotlin.kotlinOptions {
    jvmTarget = "1.8"
}
```

Is it anything in my configuration which is making this empty build folder appear?

Thank for the help!

Comment: Some task/plugin is creating the directory. Is it interfering with development somehow?

Comment: No but if good to know what it is happening? im going to have a large project so its going to be annoying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gradle automatically adds build directory in every project (it is normal, every Gradle project has such directories).

If you look in folders of your subprojects (messaging, restapi, etc), you'll probably see similar build folder there. Later you may add more gradle plugins that will store their data in these directories.

IntelliJ IDEA automatically signs these directories as excluded, so IDE does not process any files in them. If you are using Git, add these directories in your .gitignore file (just add "build" line in it, it will remove all build folders for all subprojects from VCS). And if you are VERY annoyed seeing this folders, you can hide excluded folders in IDEA.

Comment: Thank you :) That was the answer i wanted :)

Comment: All true, but doesn't answer the most important part of the question, what the heck is this sessions folder?

Answer (score 0):

You can run `./gradlew clean assemble --debug` and find such entry:

```
[org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.KotlinGradleFinishBuildHandler] [KOTLIN] Deleted session-is-alive flag file: build/kotlin/sessions/...
```

source:

https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/master/libraries/tools/kotlin-gradle-plugin/src/main/kotlin/org/jetbrains/kotlin/gradle/plugin/KotlinGradleFinishBuildHandler.kt

Perhaps, this are the culprit's lines, which don't take folder into account:

```
            for (file in sessionFiles) {
                file.delete()
                log.kotlinDebug { DELETED_SESSION_FILE_PREFIX + file.relativeToRoot(rootProject) }
            }
```